# How to extract the cursor and integer value from an array of Object class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a method which returns an array of Objects (the father class of all classes in Java). Array contains 2 types of data as you can see `objArray[0] is a int;` and `objArray[1] is a cursor;`

```
public Object[] search_record(String rollNo) {

    Object[] objArray = new Object[2];

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " where roll_no = ?", new String[] { rollNo });
    int count = cur.getCount();

    objArray[0] = count;
    objArray[1] = cur;

    Log.i("Records count", count + "");

    return objArray;

}
```

Now I am unable to extract these values back in the original values `i.e int and cursor`. I'm getting the array like this.

```
Object[] objArray = dbHelper.search_record("08cs18");
int x = ((Integer) objArray[1]).intValue();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) objArray[0];
```

but application crashes with `classCastException`

Technically this is possible, I think.

Comment: @Alex is it really mother class? why not father class

Comment: Used to be in older versions. In Java 7 it's got renamed to granpa class anyway so never mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks pretty simple to me. Look at your statement:

> objArray[0] is a int; and objArray[1] is a cursor;

and then the code:

```
Object[] objArray = dbHelper.search_record("08cs18");
int x = ((Integer) objArray[1]).intValue();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) objArray[0];
```

You're treating them the wrong way round - as of `objArray[1]` is the integer, and `objArray[0]` is the cursor. Just switch the indexes round.

**Or**, preferably... create your own class to encapsulate "a cursor and a count":

```
public final class CursorAndCount {
    private final int count;
    private final Cursor cursor;

    public CursorAndCount(int count, Cursor cursor) {
        this.count = count;
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Then you can change `search_record` (which should be called `searchRecord`) to return a `CursorAndCount` - and the calling code will immediately be more readable.

Mind you, given that you're getting the count from the cursor anyway, why don't you just return the cursor? Surely the caller can use `Cursor.getCount()` themselves, can't they?

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing the indexes, the cursor is in position `1` and the int is in position `0`. Try this:

```
int x = ((Integer) objArray[0]).intValue();
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) objArray[1];
```

You see, this is *exactly* the kind of problems that make using an object array with mixed data types a bad idea. You're better off creating a new class (a "transfer object") with the attributes that you want to return, and return an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3):

You are using indexes other way round. 0 for int and 1 for Cursor.